# SQLLDR with Sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am using **sqlldr** for uploading data to oracle table from a csv.
For one column i need to use SEQUENCE.
My control file looks like this.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE "D:\WORKER\ADS4014_GeneralJobWorkers_1426054269727.csv"
BADFILE dataFile.bad
APPEND INTO TABLE GJobWorkers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(JobId,UserId,EmpId,ChkInTme,ChkOutTme,tDate,TotalHrs,JobCode,Modified_Time,GJ_SEQ "jobs_GJ.nextval")
```

But i get error in the log file :

```
   Error on table GJobWorkers, column GJ_SEQ.
   Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
```

Can anyone help me doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe your table.

Comment: Did you try to add `trailing nullcols` to control file, as error suggests? [Example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1004664).

Comment: Got it working. I used EXPRESSION in the command line like this : GJ_SEQ EXPRESSION "jobs_GJ.nextval"